# error on boot up

Tags: 13.04

I installed 13.04 on my notebook and when I restarted it after the grub menu I got this `error: sparse file not allowed` followed by `press any key to continue....` and then it booted up. I formatted the partition to btrfs, is that the reason I am getting this error message?

Answer (score 0):

Might be. You could just reinstall GRUB (or another boot manager if you like) to fix it - that would probably get rid of the error.

Comment: you wrote "probably" which means you are just suggesting, you have not encountered and solved the above problem. I don't want to keep trying different things. I want the right solution. thanks for suggesting though.